# Using BigDecimal field in @Query and populating it with @Param field is throwing Sql Error

Tags: spring-data-jpa

This following is the query i am using for setting BigDecimal value in Query but failing as error in SQL Syntax

```
@Query(value="Select f.id,s.student_id,f.feesPaid,f.fees_pending,f.paid_datetime from Fees f inner join Student s where f.feesPaid > :amt")
    List<Fees> findFirst3ByFeesPaidGreaterThan( @Param(value = "amt") BigDecimal amt);
```

the following is the error

```
Hibernate: select fees0_.id as col_0_0_, student1_.student_id as col_1_0_, fees0_.fees_paid as col_2_0_, fees0_.fees_pending as col_3_0_, fees0_.paid_datetime as col_4_0_ from fees fees0_ inner join student student1_ on where fees0_.fees_paid>?
2019-05-07 20:06:16.779  WARN 21752 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2019-05-07 20:06:16.779 ERROR 21752 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where fees0_.fees_paid>500' at line 1
```

I am able to use the query method name but i wanted to do it using Query as mentioned above.

Comment: Not sure that is related to the `BigDecimal` could you remove the parameter and replace it with a constant in the query?
Also is this supposed to be JPQL? It looks more like SQL to me in which case you'll need to add a `nativeQuery=true` to the annotation.

Comment: I tried to replace it with constant ex: `where f.feesPaid > 100` and `where f.feesPaid > java.math.BigDecimal(100)` and lot of other combinations but it throws the same error. Also it is not nativeQuery, which i do not want to use for this scenario.

Comment: So `BigDecimal` isn't the problem. Please show us the `Student` and `Fees` classes, especially how you modelled their relationship.